# Throttling Webservice calls

Tags: web-services

We have a web service API, where we will receive an input parameter value say for eg: X, Y, Z (Its a mandatory field in API). Also we have a GUI to configure throttle limit for each value (X = 100, Y = 50, Z = 30). Also this web service API is running on multiple nodes. Using an internal loadbalancer(LVS) the load is getting shared across multiple nodes.  Now when we are receiving the request we have to throttle the incoming request using the limit configured. Please let me know any better suggestion or approach to proceed further on this.

We are using AXIS 2 framework for web service API.

Comment: this has come up before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209411/throttle-http-request-in-java-servlet. If you want a more polished solution look at something like apache camel http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html

Comment: Yes.. i have seem them but my requirement is to implement throttling at Cluster level. Is is possible to implement the same with camel.?

Comment: not unless you make your servlet filter cluster aware (ie integrate with a cache) or just set the throttle for each node to the correct fraction of the overall limit.